# Select closest element of given type above an element of given type

Tags: jquery

How can one select the closest element of given type which is above an element of a given type?

For instance...

`this` is currently `$('#j1_95_anchor')`, and I wish to select the `<li>` with an id of `15.0`.  Note that I currently don't have this id value.

```
<ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
    <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="3"
        aria-labelledby="15.0_anchor" aria-expanded="true" id="15.0" class="jstree-node jstree-open" aria-busy="false"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="15.0_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Volts_AB</a>
        <ul role="group" class="jstree-children" style="">
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_90_anchor" id="j1_90" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_90_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>ID: 15</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"
                aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_91_anchor" id="j1_91" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_91_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Name: Volts_AB</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"
                aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_92_anchor" id="j1_92" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_92_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Description: Voltage Phase A-B</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem"
                aria-selected="false" aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_93_anchor" id="j1_93" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_93_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Units: volts</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"
                aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_94_anchor" id="j1_94" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="j1_94_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon" role="presentation"></i>Type: Analog Input</a></li>
            <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="true"
                aria-level="4" aria-labelledby="j1_95_anchor" id="j1_95" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf jstree-last">
                    <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i>
                    <a class="jstree-anchor addPoint editable editable-click jstree-clicked" href="#" id="j1_95_anchor" data-original-title="" title=""><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>Add Point</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The following will work, but I feel there is probably a more straight forward approach:

```
$(this).closest('ul').closest('li');
```

I was thinking there might be something like:

$(this).closest('ul > li');

Comment: why don't you target the `id` directly ?! it's suppose to be unique anyway!

Comment: @kapreski  `xeditable()` is applied to all `a.addPoint` elements using https://github.com/pie6k/jquery.initialize, and I am not directly targeting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target `li#15.0` contains parent `ul` of the element, so:

```
$(this).parents('li').last()
```

Answering strictly your question "element of given type above an element of given type" you can use:

```
$(this).closest('li:has(ul)')
```

Normal selectors apply.

Comment: I didn't think your first solution, but it certainly does.  https://jsfiddle.net/oz9dqrvj/

Comment: @user1032531 sadly, no. First doesn't really work. Your fiddle is printing always from `test1` variable. But second does. And with a change first does too. Thing is which is more convenient?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it would.  But I like your second solution.  You too?

Comment: Yes, it's concise and expressive enough that allows to think 'the right way': parent element of type `li` that *has* an `ul` instead of backwards: `ul` parent then `ll` parent of that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try this too:

```
 $(this).closest("[id='15.0']");
```

Also you can use this:

```
$(this).closest('ul.jstree-children').children("li");
```

And if you like **tricky ways**, look at code below:

```
$("this").closest("li:only-child")
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I am currently doing.  Didn't know if there was the ability to do something like `$(this).closest('ul > li');`.

Comment: @user1032531 does that even work ?? there are two nested `ul` in your example